# google app engine static value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I am trying to make a Twitter bot in python and google app engine that will retweet myself and some of my friends just for fun.
I am thinking about using the Tweepy and get the id of the tweet in my list. If the Tweet ID is larger (meaning it come later) than the last Tweet that the bot retweeted then it will retweet it.

My problem is that I am wondering how would I store this last retweeted ID as some sort of static variable in Google App engine so that when it call this function during the refresh it will have this value to know the last retweeted ID.

I did some look around and saw that I should use the data base of the Google App Engine to do this. However, I want to keep everything as simple as possible and if possible don't want to get into the database just yet.

Is there any other way I can store this value?

Thank you for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database is exists exactly for such things, to store some data.

Appengine instances are stateless, with unpredictable lifetime, you cannot keep state variables in memory (with exception of caching and temporary variables)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess you are right. I end up using just the database to do that. At first, I was wondering since I am only storing one value, I did not thought that I would need to build entry to a data base and such and maybe I could just store it to text file or something. So I was wondering if there were an easier way than using the database.
But it turns out that the data base in Goggle App Engine was pretty easy to understand.